# Axios import differs in electron between development and electron-packager (prod)

Tags: axios, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app (v28) that makes http requests well from the main process in development, but sends no requests once I build it with electron-packager (v17). Logging from the main process shows that

```
const axios = require('axios')
```

in development is importing the expected axios [instance](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/8befb86efb101ef9dc1d1c16d77d2bf42600727f/lib/axios.js#L47), but the packaged production bundle is importing the wrap function returned from [this bind util](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/8befb86efb101ef9dc1d1c16d77d2bf42600727f/lib/helpers/bind.js#L4).

as evidenced by [logging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log) this in production

```
const axios = require('axios')
log.info('http', axios)
```

and receiving

```
[info]  http [function] function wrap() {
    return fn.apply(thisArg, arguments);
  }
```

How I can get the electron-packager build to import the correct axios instance?

Comment: any ideas on how to debug this?